# Kotlin test not found intelliJ

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I have looked at all the other responses to this but they don't seem to be applicable to me.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/kotlin.test/kotlin.test/

I am trying to access this from a scratch file or .kt file, and it isn't on the dropdown to select it.

[image: Example here]

Project is using JDK 15.

Answer (score 0):

Include this dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-test/1.1.51

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.1.51
```